# How do you keep people from seeing string literals in compiled class files?

Tags: java, string, jar, string-literals, .class-file

When you compile a .java file into a .class file, if you had a line like

```
String s = "This is a String"
```

If you open up the .class file in a text editor, you will see

```
This is a String
```

Somewhere in the file amidst the gobblety gook.

Which is fine and dandy for most stuff, but not when dealing with sensitive information like API keys.

Of course, one alternative is to read the API key in from another file, but that just makes it EASIER to find the key, as now the person can just open "key.txt" when they open the .jar file.

So how do you encrypt a string literal in your .class file?

Comment: Most convenient way would be to remove any sensitive information from your code and store it in a (possibly encrypted) repository of some sort.

Comment: I have the same problem - when I decompile others apps (Android apk) this is the first thing to search and which actually leads to reverse-engineer the apk and understand decompiled code

Answer (score 6):

When you send code to a 3rd party, you loose all control over it. Even if you where to embed the API key as an encrypted string, an attacker could still try, and potentially succeed in breaking it, which would make all your encryption/decryption efforts in vain.

The best solution, in my opinion, would be to not provide any sensitive information within the application, but rather provide it with an ID of some sort. Any sensitive values which it needs would be then pulled through the use of a secure connection.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a key to access a 3rd party API there is no way to protect that key from the end-user IF you ship it with your code / application or you want your application to be able to access the 3rd party API without a middleman.

The end-user could just read all data send from your app to the end-point and know the API key. Regardless of any measures you took to encrypt it you will need to send it atleast once decrypted to the 3rd party.

The safe way to do this is to require your user to log in to a service provided by you, send a request to YOUR service and then YOUR service (which is presumably not located on the machine of your end-user) sends a request to the API with the key. So the end-user never knows of the key.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the information in the class file, the decryption key should come from outside of the class. You can crypt the data, but if you have all the information *within the class file*, you are lost.

You should store API keys in config files. You have a different API keys for development and for the live, right?

Other possible solution is to use [KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html), which allows you to store sensitive information in publicly accessible format. Only the holder of the secret key can decrypt the sensitive data.

Comment: I will have a release key when Riot approves the app, for now I don't, but my current API key couldn't handle mass-use right now anyway. :P

Either way though, the API key and the encryption key would both end up in the same .jar file when a user runs it on their computer, even if they were in different files within the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you keep that information encrypted in your class, a hacker can find the mechanism to decrypt that from your code only. So IMHO it's better to keep that encrypted information in some other file, and read that file. Also, restrict the access to that file using OS security mechanisms.